# Are the elements of a vector field real functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am currently trying to understand the definition of differentiation of scalar fields. In doing so, I have been considering the question in the title.

I have the following definition in my lecture notes: A vector field, $\underline{f}$, is a map $\underline{f}:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\underline{x} \mapsto \underline{f}(\underline{x})$.

Since $\underline{f}$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, I assume it must have $n$ components such that $\underline{f} = \begin{pmatrix} f_1 \\ f_2 \\ \vdots \\ f_n \end{pmatrix}$. So does this mean that $\underline{f}(\underline{x}) = \begin{pmatrix} f_1(x_1) \\ f_2(x_2) \\ \vdots \\ f_n(x_n) \end{pmatrix}$, when the $f_i$ are real functions $f_i: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, each component $f_i$ may depend on *all* the variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$.
In other words, it's $f_i \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, not $f_i \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

(And by the way, your phrasing “Since $\underline{f}$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ [...]” is misleading. The reason for $\underline{f}$ having $n$ components is that the *codomain* is $\mathbb{R}^n$, not that the *domain* is $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Comment: Ah yes, you're right I mispoke. Originally I had written "Since $\underline{f} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ [...]", but I wanted to change it since that didn't exactly sound right either...